Use Spark in Scala to read sequence files containing multiple schemas and write to avro
I need to read sequence files that contains messages with different schemas:

File 1

message A
message B


File 2

message B
...



Split them by message type then write the result to avro:

message_a/data.avro
message_b/data.avro

Using Spark, I'm able to read and parse the data:
spark.sparkContext.sequenceFile(path, classOf[LongWritable], classOf[BytesWritable]).map { (key, value) =>
  val record: GenericRecord = parseValue(value)
  val messageType = extractType(record)
  messageType -> record
}

But from there I'm not sure how to pursue, I've tried sequence file writer but I'm not able to write a proper avro file.
